# Using string interpolation in React.js regex function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string-interpolation

I am having some issues using string interpolation in a regex, however I have also tried to log it to the console and I can see that I am doing it incorrectly.

I am trying to loop through an array of weather types to see if my API request returned a type of weather which requires me to add a class to one of my elements in the UI.

I iniitally thought the issue was using `array[x]` in the regex, but I have assigned this to a variable `p` and am still getting the same result.

```
let weatherTypes = ['rain', 'clouds', 'snow', 'clear', 'thunderstorm'];

for (var x= 0; x <= weatherTypes.length; x++) {
    let p = weatherTypes[x];
    console.log(p)
    var searchPattern = `/${p}/i`;
    var result = this.state.description.match(searchPattern);

    console.log(`splash--weather-${p}`);

    if(result !== null) {
        var element = document.getElementById("splashContact");
        element.classList.add(`splash--weather-${weatherTypes[0]}` );
    }
}
```

The logic to add the class works when I abstract it out of the for loop so I know that part is working fine.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

**edit** Have now used backticks instead of quotation marks

Comment: You should use the back ticks instead of the quotation marks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals 
And BTW, why are you manually manipulating the DOM, if it's allegedly a React project?

Comment: @mbojko hey perfect thank you - would I have to enclose the search pattern in back ticks? And any suggestions on how to add a class without manipulating the DOM - incredibly new to React :)

Answer (score 0):

`searchPattern` is a string so you just need to use the `RegExp` constructor before using it.

```
var searchPattern = `${p}/i`;
var searchPatternRegex = RegExp(`${searchPattern}`);
```